# deleting apex class without dependency check

Tags: apex, deployment

I remember I was not able to delete apex class when you are using class on another controller or components. However I can delete apex class even I am using on another page and the page is not deleted yet.

Why this is happening? Is it bug or I accidentally enable something?

Comment: You can only do this in Sandboxes.  It will simply cause an error and tell you to fix/recompile your classes.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I believe at some point they relaxed the metadata checks to prevent catch-22 situations, such as not being able to delete class A because page B uses it, and not being able to delete page B because class A uses it.